# rotate object around its coordinates

Tags: 3d, webgl

If I want to rotate object around its local coordinates into world (global) coordinates. From theory: I need translate it to (0,0) global coordinates, then rotate and translate it back to its global coordinates.

But if object already on (0,0) global coordinates? then I don't need to translate it. But something goes wrong.

This is vertices and indices for cube:

```
export const cubeIndices = [
  0, 1, 2,
  0, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6,
  4, 6, 7,
  5, 0, 3,
  5, 3, 6,
  1, 4, 7,
  1, 7, 2,
  5, 4, 1,
  5, 1, 0,
  3, 2, 7,
  3, 7, 6,
]

export const cubeData = [
-0.5 ,-0.5, 1.0,
0.5, -0.5, 1.0,
0.5 ,0.5 ,1.0,
-0.5, 0.5 ,1.0,
0.5, -0.5 ,0.0,
-0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
-0.5, 0.5 ,0.0,
0.5, 0.5,0.0,
]
```

Without any transformation object renders without issues.
[image: My cube]

I want to rotate it around it's Y axe. My next step in draw function is:

```
mat4.rotateY(shape.transformMatrix,shape.transformMatrix,0.01)
```

But got:
[image: Bad cube]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The center of the cube is not (0, 0, 0), it is (0, 0, 0.5). Change the z coordinates from 0 and 1 to -0.5 respectively 0.5.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of the cube is not (0, 0, 0), it is (0, 0, 0.5). When you rotate around the cube around the y axis, then it is rotated around the center of the world, which is (0, 0, 0).
If you want to rotate the cube around an axis of symmetry, which is parallel to the y axis of the world, then you have to options.

Change the z coordinates from 0 and 1 to -0.5 respectively 0.5, so that the axis of symmetry of the cube is in the center of the world:

```
export const cubeData = [
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
]
```

---

Of course this can be done by a translation matrix too. Create a separated rotation matrix and translation matrix. The translation has to applied to the vertices first and has to do the same, as if you would manually change the z component of each vertex b y -0.5.

The rotation matrix has to be initialized by the identity matrix:

```
mat4.identity(rotationMat);
```

The translation matrix has to contain the translation along the z axis (-0.5):

```
var translation = vec3.create();
vec3.set(translation, 0, 0, -0.5);
mat4.identity(translateMat);
mat4.translate(translateMat, translateMat, translation);
```

The translation matrix and rotation matrix have to be concatenate (multiply). Note, you have to respect the order of the transformation. First translate the model then rotate the model.
Since the rotation matrix is separated, it can be changed continuously:

```
mat4.rotateY(rotationMat,rotationMat,0.01)
mat4.multiply(shape.transformMatrix, rotationMat, translateMat)
```